# Как можно парсить данные без авторизации?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, авторизация

Я хочу вытащить данные с сайта (использую beautiful soup), на котором я авторизирован.
Но парсится только начальная страница, незалогиненная.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что если данные достаточно часто обновлять, есть риск бана, поскольку я буду постоянно перезаходить на страницу?
Можно ли как-то обойти авторизацию или риска бана нет и система запомнит первую авторизацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данные часто обновлять, то сервер может оборвать соединение из-за подозрения на ddos.
Вот статья про авторизацию при парсинге.
[Ссылка](https://newtechaudit.ru/parsing-sajta-s-primeneniem-avtorizaczii/)